# Undesired different results with bevel modifier and vertex group

Tags: modifiers, vertex-groups, bevel

iam using bevel modifier on simple model that looks like window. I want beveled edge only on window corner so iam using vertex group. The problem Iam having that on one side it looks clean and straight as well as the corner is ok, the opposite side is beveled differently with bad results. How is that? Normals are ok, no double verteces.
[image: bevel screenshot]

Comment: Should use bevel weights https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/edge_data.html#edge-bevel-weight as limit method instead

Comment: Worked ok, thank you, I didnt think of using weights. If anyone would know why the vertex group behave like this, let me know, just curious.

Comment: Are the weights in your vertex group all over .5? I don't know why, but that qualifies for inclusion in the bevel. Why aren't the vertex weights just used as vertex bevel weights? Makes not much sense to me....

Answer (score 0):

I found a reason.

Its because I have another window right next to this. So the vertexes are connected and take the edge in count when beveling so I would have to add another edge between them to separate or the better solution was as @lemon wrote to use edge weight.

Beveled by edge weight
[image: edge weight]

When add a weight between the windows it makes the same artifacts like when I used vertex group that counted in that edges between windows.
[image: undesired artifacts]